# RDP automatic log off after 15 minutes

Tags: session, ssms, remote-desktop, rdp

I am having an issue when I connect to a server via RDP. The server is a Windows Server 2016 Standard; and after 15 minutes of inactivity from my side, it seems to close the session, closing all the applications I had open etc...

This is extremely irritating, especially when I am writing code in ‘sql server management studio’, or if I am moving files… I then re-connect via RDP, and it successfully loads a new session.

I have tried this solution, but did not fix it:

**Browse to Computer Configuration --> Administrative Templates --> Windows Components --> Remote Desktop Services --> Remote Desktop Session Host --> Session Time Limits.
Enable the "Set time limit for disconnected sessions" and set it to Never**
[image]

Comment: Wrong forum since not programming related and possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1144853/how-do-i-keep-an-rdp-session-alive-from-the-client-side

Answer (score 1):

You can try to enable RDP keep alive functionnality in the registry:

In regedit.exe as admin:

```
Go to the location HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server
Create or edit the DWORD value of KeepAliveEnable
Set it to 1.
Save and quit
```

see https://superuser.com/a/1144885/745652